# Using inline variable substitution in ModelBuilder for iterating through Excel sheets?

Tags: modelbuilder, excel, arcgis-pro, error-000354

I need to join .xlsx tables to a states.shp files based on StateName, and then export the joined features into a geodatabase. I have several excel files ("XX2011, XX2012, XX2013, etc.), and need the output feature classes to reflect the names of the input tables.

I'm using ModelBuilder to iterate the process, but keeping getting errors. I don't think I am using the inline variable substitution correctly, but the ArcGISPro documentation isn't helping.

[image]

I've gotten different errors depending on how I've configured it. No matter what I seem to get:

> ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
>
> ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
>
> Failed to execute (Calculate Value).

Comment: You are trying to remove the $ symbol from the sheet name but then return a _table object_. Suggest you change the return value to a string?